# Difference between System and a custom namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces

I've been writing a set of code that I would like to use in many places. I have put it in a namesapce called Limits. Now, I add the code file to the project, put `using Limits` at the top of a form file that needs to use its classes (along with `using System` and all the standard ones I need).

When I want to use something like `System.UInt32` after including System, I can just type `UInt32` and it knows the correct namespace.

Is there something to add to my custom namspace that allows this, or must I include it in the forms namespace?

Edit:

```
using System;
using Limits;

namespace Sandbox {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        Check lim = new Check(3, 1);
}
```

Check is a class inside of the Limits namespace, was throwing an error however.  No that I've stripped it that far down, it seems to not fail. Not sure what I changed so I will have to go back and compare versions.

Comment: If you added `using Limits;` then all of the types declared in that namespace should be imported into the local scope, just like with any other namespace.  Why do you suspect that this doesn't work?

Comment: Huh? VS knows `UInt32` because you've included `System`. If you've added your `Limits` namespace, you should get the exact same functionality for the types you defined in `Limits`. Where is this question even coming from?

Comment: You need to add the reference to the project of your 'limits' as well to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access your classes without specifying the namespace just by adding

```
using Limits;
```

at the top of your class.

One exception to this is if you have a name collision, meaning you have a class in `Limits` with the same name as a class in another namespace that you're using.  In that case you need to specify *which* class you're talking about.

For example, if you have a class called `Form` in `Limits` (and you are also using the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace) you'd have to include the namespace when using the class:

```
Limits.Form = form = new Limits.Form();
```

You could as an alternative use an *alias* in your using statements:

```
using MyForm = Limits.Form;

...

MyForm form = new MyForm();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when a build fails, you'll have a situation where classes that are in a namespace in a referenced project don't show up. If that is the case, you'll want to rebuild the project that your `Limits` namespace is in.